# Creating data.frames with names from vector

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector of character values. Is it possible to create multiple empty data.frames with names taken from the vector (for example while looping over that vector) and refer to those data.frames later in the code by their name, getting those names from character vector?

```
names <- c ("data.a","data.z","data.g")
```

I want to loop over the names vector and create empty data.frames data.a data.z data.g etc and be able to assign values to them later also by looping over names.

Comment: Create a `list` of data.frames ...

Comment: Thanks for the tip - would it be possible to save the list to harddrive and load later as with usual dataframe?

Comment: Of course. You could use the `saveRDS` function to save the whole list or loop over the list to save each data.frame with `write.csv` if you need those in a different software.

Comment: It seems you want to populate the data.frames later by looping over them. Unless you initialize the dataframes in advance, this will be quite slow in R.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually it was a toy example - i will be pulling data from API and storing it in the dataframes/lists of dataframes.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use `sapply` to create the list:

```
nms <- c ("data.a", "data.z", "data.g")
lst <- sapply(nms, function(x) x=data.frame() )
str(lst)
List of 3
 $ data.a:'data.frame': 0 obs. of  0 variables
 $ data.z:'data.frame': 0 obs. of  0 variables
 $ data.g:'data.frame': 0 obs. of  0 variables
```

and refering to them by:

```
> lst[[1]]
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
> lst$data.a
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
 nms <- c("data.a","data.z","data.g")
 lst <- setNames(replicate(3, data.frame()), nms)
```